# Serial.print and char[] & null

Tags: print

I don't write a lot of C, so I'm always discovering things I only partly understand in the Arduino variety. One of these is how `Serial.print` handles `char[]`.

Does Serial.print always require a null terminator? In the case of (say) `Serial.print(88, DEC);` is a null implied?

What happens in the following cases?

```
char buff[3] = "ABC"; // warned because no room for a null
Serial.print(buff);   // will absence of a null cause overrun?

char buff[4] = "ABC"; // now there's a null
Serial.print(buff);   // will the null character be sent too?
```

Any references appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a char* you need to also pass some way of telling the function where it ends. In C that is usually the null terminator and that's all a null terminator is for. If that is missing then you get a buffer overrun.

The null terminator is not sent.

Answer (score 3):

The "Serial" is a object/class and that makes it possible to have more than one function for [`Serial.print()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print). According to the type of the parameter the proper `Serial.print()` is selected.

This is the include file for the `Serial.print()`: [Print.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h)
And these are the possibilities:

- `size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *);`
- `size_t print(const String &);`
- `size_t print(const char[]);`
- `size_t print(char);`
- `size_t print(unsigned char, int = DEC);`
- `size_t print(int, int = DEC);`
- `size_t print(unsigned int, int = DEC);`
- `size_t print(long, int = DEC);`
- `size_t print(unsigned long, int = DEC);`
- `size_t print(double, int = 2);`
- `size_t print(const Printable&);`

The reference for [`Serial.print()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) is short, but it explains pretty well that those different parameters are possible.

Your `Serial.print(88, DEC);` does not use a string of text, it uses the integer number 88.

As soon as a string of text is used, it should be zero-terminated.
The line `char buff[3] = "ABC";` is indeed wrong, as you already wrote. That is one of the things of the 'c' language. The "ABC" gets a zero-terminater and that makes 4 bytes.